# VB6 Is it possible to implement the Singleton design pattern?

Tags: vb6, singleton

Within VB6 is it possible to implement the Singleton design pattern?

Currently the legacy system I work on has a large about of IO performed by multiple instances of a particular class. It is desirable to clean up all these instances and have the IO performed by one instance only. This would allow us to add meaningful logging and monitoring to the IO routines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this, and it depends if this is a multi-project application with different dlls or a single project.

If it is single project and there is a large amount of code that you are worrying about chaning/breaking then I suggest the following:

1. Given a class clsIOProvider that is instantiated all over the place, create a module modIOProvider in the same project.
2. For each method / property defined in clsIOProvider, create the same set of methods in modIOProvider.
3. The implementation of those methods, as well as the instance data of the class, should be cloned from clsIOProvider to modIOProvider.
4. All methods and properties in clsIOProvider should be chnaged to forward to the implementation in modIOProvider.  The class should no longer have an instance data.
5. (Optional) If the class requires the use of the constructor and destructor (Initialize/Terminate), forward those to modIOProvider as well.  Add a single instnace counter within modIOProvider to track the number of instances.  Run your initialzation code when the instance counter goes from 0 to 1, and your termination code when the instance counter goes from 1 to 0.

The advantage of this is that you do not have to change the coe in the scores of places that are utilizeing the clsIOProvider class.  They are happily unaware that the object is now effectively a singleton.

If coding a proejct from scratch I would do this a bit differently, but as a refactoring appraoch wahat I've outlined should work well.

Comment: +1 for a method with minimal impact on existing code. Although you could (1,2) create a new class clsConcreteIOProvider that implements clsIOProvider. (3) Move all the implementations from clsIOProvider into clsIOProvider (4) Change all methods and properties to forward to a private instance of clsConcreteIOProvider. (5) In the Class_Initialise set the private instance of clsConcreteIOProvider to a single instance (singleton) using a technique from Deanna's answer. One benefit is that you can rely on VB/COM reference counting to initalise/terminate the underlying singleton if required.

Comment: Yes, that is an excellent alternate way of doing it in the same spirit of zero impact on existing code.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to only create and use one instance of an object. How you do it depends on your code what it does and where it's called from.

In one process, you can just have a single variable in a global module with an instance, maybe with a factory function that creates it on first use.

If it's shared by multiple process, it complicates things, but can be done with an ActiveX EXE and the Running Object Table.

Comment: @MarkJ - The problem with a global variable is that you end up having to add If Not modGlobal.IOObject Is Nothing Then Set modGlobal.IOObject = New clsIOObject just before every use of it.  And object termination is equally difficult (if it is required).

Comment: Yep, but you can use a factory function which then allows you to do semi reference counting by having a get and a release function.

Comment: @tcarvin @Deanna I'm with Deanna. A private module level variable `mobjSingleton`, and a global function to return the module level variable. The global function would do `If Not mobjSingleton Is Nothing Then Set mobjSingleton = New clsSingleton`. You could have a global release sub if needed which would `Set mobjSingleton = Nothing`. However caution would be needed as this does not terminate references previously obtained by clients.

Comment: @MarkJ If the use-case is that the IOObject, once created, never needs to be cleaned up (no code in the Terminate) then your solution is simpler.  But as soon as the client code (the code that was creating and using the IOObject) has to start manually calling aquires and releases to do psuedo-reference counting I would not use that approach.  The OP said this code was everywhere, and that's a lot of places to have to push that change.  My suggestion, while slightly more complex, has zero impact in the client code.  It all depends...